# Use NSURLSession to check for connection response

Tags: ios

Since NSURLConnection has been deprecated in IOS 9.0, it says I have to use NSURLSession from now on. I need some help though. I use NSURLConnection with a delegate just to check if the URL gives a response. How would I do this with NSURLSession?

My code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] == 200) {
        //Do Things
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //Do other things
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the completion block renditions of `NSURLSession`. This way you enjoy cancellable, asynchronous requests, but without having to write any delegate methods. And if you don't need anything special from the session (e.g. custom caching or the like), you might use the `sharedSession` that saves you from creating and configuring the `NSURLSession`:

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        // check status code here
    }
    if (error) {
        // handle other errors here
    }
    // handle data here
}];
[task resume];
```